# How do I make this LC-3 code to count the number of 0s in the value stored in R0 and stores the result into R1

Tags: lc3

How do I modify this LC-3 code to make it count the number of 0s instead of ones

```
.ORIG x3000
      LD R2, INPUT
      AND  R0, R0, #0   ; COUNTER INITIALIZED TO ZERO
      ADD  R1, R0, #1
      ADD  R3, R0, #15
  LOOP  
      AND R4, R2, R1   
      BRz  SKIP 
      ADD R0, R0, #1
  SKIP  
      ADD R1, R1, R1
      ADD R3, R3, #-1
      BRzp  LOOP
  INPUT .FILL x1997
      .END
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you watched how it works in the debugger?  Single step this small program, and you'll see how it works.

Can you find the if-then construct in here?  An if-then construct has the form if-condition-then-action.  So, you're looking for something that has this effect:

```
if ( bit is set ) 
    R0++;
```

And you want to change it to the opposite condition, so it counts zeros instead.

```
if ( bit is clear )
    R0++;
```

Where `bit is clear` is the same as `! (bit is set)`, i.e. it is the opposite.

Note that the above is in terms of structured language like C.  In assembly, if-condition-then-action looks more like this:

```
    if ( condition is false ) goto Label1; // action is skipped if condition is false
    ..action..                             // action runs if condition is true
Label1:
```

This is because the only control structure in assembly/machine code is conditional branch, which in C looks like `if ( condition ) goto label;`

Answer (score 0):

If, i suppose, your program is OK (i don't try it) a quick modification is to flip all 0 to 1 and 1 to 0.

NOT do the job!
I leave you the exercise.

Another way, is that if you count n bit1 this mean that you have 16-n bit0...
Again NOT is your friend to compute 16-n

Note that both leave the code intact which can be used as a subroutine.

Don't forget to use HALT to stop the program